# HTML Preview Not Working With Quarto-Generated HTML File

Tags: r-markdown, quarto

I am trying to update my portfolio website with new Quarto-generated HTML files rather than my older RMarkdown-generated HTML files. I have rendered these updated files and they look great!

[image]

However, when I have uploaded this HTML to my GitHub Pages website, using htmlpreview, I get a very different picture...

[image]

Keep in mind that htmlpreview works perfectly well for my RMarkdown-renderd documents:

[image]

Here is my YAML for the Quarto document if it is of help:

```
author: "Brian Lookabaugh"
toc: true
number-sections: true
format:
  html:
    code-background: true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think using <s>`self-contained: true`</s> `embed-resources: true` would solve your case, since you would need a standalone HTML file.

```
---
author: "Brian Lookabaugh"
toc: true
number-sections: true
format:
  html:
    embed-resources: true
    code-background: true
---
```

For reference, see [this page](https://quarto.org/docs/output-formats/html-publishing.html#standalone-html) from Quarto Docs.

Comment: Worked flawlessly, thank you!

Comment: This trick doesn't seem to work at the moment, any idea?

Comment: I solved it, I think updating quarto and switching to `embed-resources` helped. Also, I realized that the my private GutHub repo token was changing often and can't make a permanent link for html preview.